# How to compile and run C files from within Notepad++ using NppExec plugin?

Tags: c, notepad++, nppexec

How can I configure the NppExec plugin for Notepad++?

I would like NppExec to compile my C files, run them, and show their output, all within Notepad++.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Here's a procedure for Perl, just adapt it for C. Hope it helps.

- Open Notepad++
- Type <kbd>F6</kbd> to open the execute window
- Write the following commands:
- `npp_save` ← Saves the current document
- `CD $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)` ← Moves to the current directory
- `perl.exe -c -w "$(FILE_NAME)"` ← executes the command perl.exe -c -w , example: `perl.exe -c -w test.pl` (-c = compile -w = warnings)
- Click on **Save**
- Type a name to save the script (e.g. "Perl Compile")
- Go to Menu **Plugins** → **Nppexec** → **advanced options** → **Menu Item** (Note: this is right BELOW 'Menu Items *')
- In the combobox titled 'Associated Script' select the script recently created in its dropdown menu, select **Add/Modify** and click **OK** → **OK**
- Restart Notepad++
- Go to Settings → Shortcut mapper → Plugins → search for the script name
- Select the shortcut to use (ie <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>), click **OK**
- Verify that you can now run the script created with the shortcut selected.

Comment: I found a manual for NppExec in the meanwhile. It's stored in \Notepad++\plugins\docs\NppExec and describes how to create compile-scripts for every kind of source code files. It helped me a lot. Your answer is true as well and probably works fine for perl scripts ( I didn't try it out). I guess it will work too for c-files if you change it. Thank you!

Comment: Using this method, the shortcut doesn't work for me unless I open the console, put my cursor there, and hit the shortcut.  If I do that, the commands will run.

Answer (score 28):

**For perl,**

To run perl script use this procedure

Requirement: You need to setup classpath variable.

Go to **plugins**->**NppExec**->**Execute**

In command section, type this

```
cmd /c cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"&&"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

Save it and give name to it.(I give Perl).

Press <kbd>OK</kbd>. If editor wants to restart, do it first.

Now press <kbd>F6</kbd> and you will find your Perl script output on below side.

Note: Not required seperate config for seperate files.

**For java**,

Requirement: You need to setup `JAVA_HOME` and `classpath` variable.

Go to plugins->NppExec->Execute

In command section, type this

```
cmd /c cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"&&"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac""$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

your `*.class` will generate on location of current folder;  despite of programming error.

**For Python,**

Use this Plugin  [Python Plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/PyNPP/)

Go to plugins->NppExec-> Run file in Python intercative

By using this you can run scripts within Notepad++.

**For PHP,**

No need for different configuration just download this plugin.

[PHP Plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpfornppplugin/?source=directory) 
and done.

**For C language,**

Requirement: You need to setup classpath variable.
                I am using MinGW compiler.

Go to plugins->NppExec->Execute

paste this into there

```
   NPP_SAVE

   CD $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)

   C:\MinGW32\bin\gcc.exe -g "$(FILE_NAME)" 

   a
```

(Remember to give above four lines separate lines.)

Now, give name, save and ok.

Restart Npp.

Go to plugins->NppExec->Advanced options.

Menu Item->Item Name (I have C compiler)

Associated Script-> from combo box select the above name of script.

Click on Add/modify and Ok.

Now assign shortcut key as given in first answer.

Press <kbd>F6</kbd> and select script or just press shortcut(I assigned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>).

**For C++,**

Only change g++ instead of `gcc` and `*.cpp` instead on `*.c`

That's it!!

Comment: I need this `...javac" "$(FULL...` to make java work. (Add a space)

Comment: For the C instructions, when I get to plugins, I don't see NppExec listed, only NppExport and NppFTP.  Is NppExec an extra plugin that needs to be installed?

Comment: Update: Easiest way to install NppExec is: Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Find and choose NppExec -> Install -> restart Notepad++

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code for compling and running java source code:
- Open Notepadd++
- Hit **F6**
- Paste this code

```
npp_save <-- Saves the current document
CD $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) <-- Moves to the current directory
javac "$(FILE_NAME)" <-- compiles your file named *.java
java "$(NAME_PART)" <-- executes the program
```

The Java Classpath variable has to be set for this...

Another useful site: http://www.scribd.com/doc/52238931/Notepad-Tutorial-Compile-and-Run-Java-Program

Answer (score 4):

I personally use the following batch script that can be used on many types of files (C, makefile, Perl scripts, shell scripts, batch, ...).

How to use it:

1. Install **NppExec** plugin
2. Store this file in the Notepad++ user directory (**%APPDATA%/Notepad++**) under the name *runNcompile.bat* (but you can name it whatever you like).
3. while checking the option "Follow $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" in NppExec menu
4. Add a **NppExec** command `"$(SYS.APPDATA)\Notepad++\runNcompile.bat" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` (optionally, you can put `npp_save` on the first line to save the file before running it)
5. Assign a special key (I reassigned <kbd>F12</kbd>) to launch the script.

This page explains quite clearly the global flow: https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2015/08/configure-notepad-to-run-c-cpp-and-java-programs.html

Hope it can help

```
  @echo off

REM ----------------------
REM ----- ARGUMENTS ------
REM ----------------------
set FPATH=%~1
set FILE=%~n1
set DIR=%~dp1
set EXTENSION=%~x1
REM ----------------------



REM ----------------------
REM ------- CONFIG -------
REM ----------------------
REM C Compiler (gcc.exe or cl.exe) + options + object extension
set CL_compilo=gcc.exe
set CFLAGS=-c "%FPATH%"
set OBJ_Ext=o
REM GNU make
set GNU_make=make.exe
REM ----------------------




IF /I "%FILE%"==Makefile GOTO _MAKEFILE
IF /I %EXTENSION%==.bat GOTO _BAT
IF /I %EXTENSION%==.sh GOTO _SH
IF /I %EXTENSION%==.pl GOTO _PL
IF /I %EXTENSION%==.tcl GOTO _TCL
IF /I %EXTENSION%==.c GOTO _C
IF /I %EXTENSION%==.mak GOTO _MAKEFILE
IF /I %EXTENSION%==.mk GOTO _MAKEFILE
IF /I %EXTENSION%==.html GOTO _HTML
echo Format of argument (%FPATH%) not supported!
GOTO END


REM Batch shell files (bat)
:_BAT
call "%FPATH%"
goto END


REM Linux shell scripts (sh)
:_SH
call sh.exe "%FPATH%"
goto END


REM Perl Script files (pl)
:_PL
call perl.exe "%FPATH%"
goto END


REM Tcl Script files (tcl)
:_TCL
call tclsh.exe "%FPATH%"
goto END


REM Compile C Source files (C)
:_C
REM MAKEFILES...
IF EXIST "%DIR%Makefile" ( cd "%DIR%" )
IF EXIST "%DIR%../Makefile" ( cd "%DIR%/.." )
IF EXIST "%DIR%../../Makefile" ( cd "%DIR%/../.." )
IF EXIST "Makefile" ( 
    call %GNU_make% all
    goto END
)
REM COMPIL...
echo -%CL_compilo% %CFLAGS%-
call %CL_compilo% %CFLAGS%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    echo -%CL_compilo% -o"%DIR%%FILE%.exe" "%DIR%%FILE%.%OBJ_Ext%"-
    call %CL_compilo% -o"%DIR%%FILE%.exe" "%DIR%%FILE%.%OBJ_Ext%" 
)
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (del "%DIR%%FILE%.%OBJ_Ext%")
goto END


REM Open HTML files in web browser (html and htm)
:_HTML
start /max /wait %FPATH%
goto END

REM ... END ...
:END
echo.
IF /I "%2" == "-pause" pause
```

Comment: Please tell me how to use this script?

Comment: @BrolyLSSJ  I improved my description to understand more clearly how to use it. Hope it is clear enough.

Answer (score 4):

I've made a single powerfull script that will:

-Compile and run multi language code like `C`, `C++`, `Java`, `Python` and `C#`.
-Delete the old executable before compiling code.
-Only run the code if it's compiled successfully.

I've also made a very noob friendly tutorial [Transform Notepad++ to Powerful Multi Languages IDE](http://bitsnapper.com/notepad-plus-plus-to-powerful-multi-language-ide/) which contains some additional scripts like to only run or Compile the code, run code inside CMD etc.

```
npp_console 1               //open console
NPP_CONSOLE -               //disable output of commands
npe_console m-              //disable unnecessary output
con_colour bg= 191919 fg= F5F5F5    //set console colors
npp_save                //save the file
cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)         //follow current directory
NPP_CONSOLE +               //enable output
IF $(EXT_PART)==.c GOTO C       //if .c file goto C label
IF $(EXT_PART)==.cpp GOTO CPP       //if .cpp file goto CPP label
IF $(EXT_PART)==.java GOTO JAVA     //if .java file goto JAVA label
IF $(EXT_PART)==.cs GOTO C#     //if .cs file goto C# label
IF $(EXT_PART)==.py GOTO PYTHON     //if .py file goto PYTHON label
echo FILE SAVED
GOTO EXITSCRIPT             // else treat it as a text file and goto EXITSCRIPT
//C label
:C                                                                  
cmd /C if exist "$(NAME_PART).exe" cmd /c del "$(NAME_PART).exe"//delete existing executable file if exists
gcc "$(FILE_NAME)" -o $(NAME_PART)              //compile file
IF $(EXITCODE) != 0 GOTO EXITSCRIPT             //if any compilation error then abort
echo C CODE COMPILED SUCCESSFULLY:              //print message on console
$(NAME_PART)                                            //run file in cmd, set color to green and pause cmd after output
GOTO EXITSCRIPT                         //finally exits

:CPP
cmd /C if exist "$(NAME_PART).exe" cmd /c del "$(NAME_PART).exe"
g++ "$(FILE_NAME)" -o $(NAME_PART)
IF $(EXITCODE) != 0 GOTO EXITSCRIPT
echo C++ CODE COMPILED SUCCESSFULLY:
$(NAME_PART)
GOTO EXITSCRIPT

:JAVA
cmd /C if exist "$(NAME_PART).class" cmd /c del "$(NAME_PART).class"
javac $(FILE_NAME) -Xlint
IF $(EXITCODE) != 0 GOTO EXITSCRIPT
echo JAVA CODE COMPILED SUCCESSFULLY:
java $(NAME_PART)
GOTO EXITSCRIPT

:C#
cmd /C if exist "$(NAME_PART).exe" cmd /c del "$(NAME_PART).exe"
csc $(FILE_NAME)
IF $(EXITCODE) != 0 GOTO EXITSCRIPT
echo C# CODE COMPILED SUCCESSFULLY:
$(NAME_PART)
GOTO EXITSCRIPT

:PYTHON
echo RUNNING PYTHON SCRIPT IN CMD:              //python is a script so no need to compile
python $(NAME_PART).py
GOTO EXITSCRIPT

:EXITSCRIPT
// that's all, folks!
```

Comment: Your link for the noob friendly tutorial is currently broken.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend my solution.
My situation: g++(cygwin) on win10

My solution:
Write a .bat batch file and execute compiler in that batch.
compileCpp.bat

```
@echo off  
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\cygwin64\bin\
rm %~n1.exe
c++.exe -g %~dpnx1 -o %~dpn1.exe
%~n1.exe
```

Console:

```
NPP_EXEC: "runCpp"
NPP_SAVE: E:\hw.cpp
CD: E:\
Current directory: E:\
cmd /c C:\cygwin64\bin\compileCpp.bat "hw.cpp"
Process started >>>
Hello World<<< Process finished. (Exit code 0)
================ READY ================
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually compile and run C code even without the use of nppexec plugins. If you use MingW32 C compiler, use g++ for C++ language and gcc for C language.

Paste this code into the notepad++ run section

```
cmd /k cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) && gcc $(FILE_NAME) -o $(NAME_PART).exe  && $(NAME_PART).exe && pause
```

It will compile your C code into exe and run it immediately. It's like a build and run feature in CodeBlock. All these are done with some cmd knowledge.

Explanation:

1. cmd /k is used for testing.

   - Full explanation @ http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html
2. cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)

   - change directory to where file is located
3. && operators

   - to chain your commands in a single line
4. gcc $(FILE_NAME)

   - use GCC to compile File with its file extension.
5. -o $(NAME_PART).exe

   - this flag allow you to choose your output filename. $(NAME_PART) does not include file extension.
6. $(NAME_PART).exe

   - this alone runs your program
7. pause

   - this command is used to keep your console open after file has been executed.

For more info on notepad++ commands, go to

> http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/External_Programs

Answer (score 1):

I know this is kind of old question, but I am still adding this as an answer (hopefully, it adds to the overall answer). I had recently gone through these steps and have come up with this one.

[image: how to compile and run c program in notepad++]

I have created a step by step video tutorial for the same. (As it says, video is worth ten-thousand words!)

[How to compile and run C code in Notepad++](https://youtu.be/K63CNzEkMnA)

- 00:58​ Install MinGW (Minimalist GNU for Windows)
- 01:42​ Install GCC, GCC++ Compilers in MinGW
- 03:00​ Setup an environment variable in PATH for MinGW's gcc.exe
- 05:20​ Install NPPExec notepad++ plugin to execute C Program.
- 05:50​ Create a C Compiler script for Notepad++ NPPExec plugin
- 06:48​ Create a menu item in NPPExec for C Compiler
- 08:00​ Test run C Code from Notepad++
- 09:55​ Create keyboard shortcut for compiling and running C program
  from Notepad++ (Optional)

Hopefully, it will be useful to someone who is looking for step by step tutorial.

As always, a disclaimer that I own this YouTube channel. And It may sound like self promotion, but I hope I have given enough information in this answer to someone getting started with this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Decompile with CMD:

If those didn't work try this:

```
cmd /K g++ "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" -o "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH).exe
```

It should save where you got the file (Example: If I got file from Desktop, it will be saved as .exe on the Desktop)

I don't know if it works on 64 bits though so you can try it!

Answer (score 0):

I've written just this to execute compiling and run the file after, plus fileinputname = fileoutputname on windowsmashines, if your compilerpath is registred in the windows PATH-var:

```
NPP_SAVE
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)"
set LEN~ strrfind $(FILE_NAME) .
set EXENAME ~ substr 0 $(LEN) $(FILE_NAME)
set $(EXENAME) = $(EXENAME).exe
c++.exe "$(FILE_NAME)" -o "$(EXENAME)"
"$(EXENAME)"
```

should work for any compiler if you change c++.exe to what you want

Answer (score 0):

In windows if you are using a portable version of MinGW you must set path variable or you have error libintl-8.dll not found.
My path is C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin