# Save and Run with one Keystroke

Tags: macros, notepad++

I'm using winPython and Notepad++ and would like to save myself some key strokes by having one key save and also run my code.

I have `C:\Users\Robin\Desktop\coding\WinPython-32bit-2.7.10.2\python-2.7.10\python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` saved onto F6, but when I try to create a macro for CTRL+S then F6, only the saving part gets recorded.

Anyone know why + how to fix it?

Comment: Assuming yur are already using NppExec: you can use `npp_save` and then `npp_run "your python path" "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`. E.g. see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980134/how-to-compile-execute-c-code-from-within-notepad

Comment: I've not been using NppExec. Maybe I should. I guess my macro stops recording because once I press the run shortcut, Npp is no longer active to record it?