# Notepad++ NppExec console warning, need explanation "C++"

Tags: c++, notepad++, compiler-warnings, nppexec

I've tried using Notepad++ to code c++ and followed a few tutorials on youtube, here's what I did:

-Installed gcc/g++ compiler using mingw64

-Installed NppExec plugin on N++

-Typed in the following compilier script and saved as C++:

> NPP_SAVE cd 
>  $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY) 
>  g++ $(FILE_NAME) 
>  cmd /c $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\program.exe

Anyways whenever compiling a program, for example a simple program

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << "Online\n";
    system("pause"); //So that cmd doesn't disappear immeadiately on running.
    return 0;
}
```

The console displays the following warning:
`"C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Courses\Projects\C\program.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."`
My question is, 
When I run the program on cmd, it runs perfectly but the error displayed during linking says that the folder does not exist in `%PATH%` 
Any explanation? 
Thank you!

Comment: `g++ $(FILE_NAME)` doesn't specify an output filename. If you go look in that directory is there a `program.exe` file or is it named `a.exe`?

Comment: @RetiredNinja 
Checked directory, file is `a.exe` not `program.exe`
Should I replace (FILE_NAME) with the current program name?

Comment: you can add -o option to g++ command: __g++ filename.c -o filename__

Comment: You probably want something like `g++ $(FILE_NAME) -o $(NAME_PART)`. If that creates `program` instead of `program.exe` then `$(NAME_PART).exe` may work better.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, what I basically did was change the script,

```
cmd /c $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\program.exe
```

To be later

```
cmd /c $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\a.exe
```

the console worked fine and even received input 
 
Here is a link to a similar problem:

[How to compile/execute C++ code from within Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27980134/17626253)