# get a console in notepad++ like Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, console, notepad++, user-input

At school we are learning PHP, and are using netbeans for this. I myself have learned how to code before i started this study and used Notepad++ so i am kinda familiar with that. My problem: We use Netbeans in class because it has an console in it and you can execute your code in it so you can use things like fget(STDIN)
I know how to get a console in Notepad++ (the plugin nppExec) but i just can't seem to get my code executed in the console

if i execute some code in my browser like echo hello world it does work
if i try to get it in my console because i want to use a user input i get this error that he cant find/get the file

So.. how do i get a console in Notepad++ like one in Netbeans

Later this day i will upload pictures to clarify of what i have tried

Comment: Notepad is a text editor, but you are referring to the functionality of an IDE. I can't be 100% sure, but I don't think you can do this?

Comment: The question is primarily about C, but there are some answers that relate to PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506400/how-to-compile-and-run-c-files-from-within-notepad-using-nppexec-plugin

Comment: Why not just install NetBeans at home?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this, even if you can, it's not a good practice because notepad++ is good as text editor. I suggest you to use some IDE like netbeans instead, soon you will get familiar with this also.